# ¿Como obtener el id de el nodo seleccionado y enviarlo a la pagina idex desde JsTree?[php/mysql]

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hola estoy utilizando Jstree plugin lo cargo correctamente pero necesito capturar el id del nodo seleccionado y ponerlo en una variable que pueda ser utilizada desde index.php, inspeccionando el codigo de jstree pero no logro como hacerlo. les dejo el codigo.

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Basic JsTree Create Update Delete</h1>

    <div class="col-md-12"><!---div de los botones crud--->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="demo_create();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> เพิ่ม</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="demo_rename();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> แก้ไข</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="demo_delete();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> ลบ</button>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div id="frmt"></div><!---div donde se carga el arbol con todos sus detalles--->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>


    <script><!---script con las funciones encargadas de seleccionar modificar actualizar y crear--->

        function demo_create() {

              var ref = $('#frmt').jstree(true),
                      sel = ref.get_selected();
              if(!sel.length) { 

                  alert('กรุณาเลือก  Node ที่ต้องการ เพิ่มข้อมูล');

                  return false;

              }

              sel = sel[0];

              sel = ref.create_node(sel, {"type":"file"});

              if(sel) {
                ref.edit(sel);
              }
        }

        function demo_rename() {
                var ref = $('#frmt').jstree(true),
                        sel = ref.get_selected();
                if(!sel.length) {
                     alert('seleccione lo que quiere renombrear');
                     return false;
                }
                sel = sel[0];
                ref.edit(sel);
        }

        function demo_delete() {

            var ref = $('#frmt').jstree(true),

            sel = ref.get_selected();

            if(!sel.length) {

                  alert('seleccione lo que quiere borrar');
                  return false;

            }else{

                if(confirm("esta seguro")){
                    if(sel == 1){

                        alert('esta seguro');

                        return false;

                    }else{
                        ref.delete_node(sel);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    $('#frmt').jstree({
         'core' : {
               'data' : {
                'url' : 'crud_response.php?operation=get_node',
                 "dataType" : "json"
               }
               ,'check_callback' : true,
         }
    }).on('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {

          $.get('crud_response.php?operation=create_node', { 'id' : data.node.id, 'parent' : data.node.parent, 'text' : data.node.text })
            .done(function (d) {
               data.instance.set_id(data.node,d);
            })
            .fail(function () {

              data.instance.refresh();
               console.log(data);
            });

    }).on('rename_node.jstree', function (e, data) {

        $.get('crud_response.php?operation=rename_node', { 'id' : data.node.id, 'text' : data.text })
            .fail(function () {

              data.instance.refresh();
        });

    }).on('delete_node.jstree', function (e, data) {


        $.get('crud_response.php?operation=delete_node', { 'id' : data.node.id})

            .fail(function () {

              data.instance.refresh();
        });

    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

y aca el archivo **crud_response.php** que es el encargdo de ejecutar el crud

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "treejs";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM tb_node";

$result_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result_query) > 0) {

    $operation = isset($_GET['operation']) ? $_GET['operation'] : NULL;

    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL;

    $parent = isset($_GET['parent']) ? $_GET['parent'] : NULL;

    $text = isset($_GET['text']) ? $_GET['text'] : NULL;

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_query)) {

        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $row["id"],
            'parent_id' => $row["parent_id"],
            'text' => $row["name"],
        );
    }

        switch($operation) {

            case 'get_node':

                $itemsByReference = array();

                // Build array of item references:
                foreach($data as $key => &$item) {
                   $itemsByReference[$item['id']] = &$item;
                   // Children array:
                   $itemsByReference[$item['id']]['children'] = array();
                   // Empty data class (so that json_encode adds "data: {}" ) 
                   $itemsByReference[$item['id']]['data'] = new StdClass();
                }

                // Set items as children of the relevant parent item.
                foreach($data as $key => &$item)
                   if($item['parent_id'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']]))
                      $itemsByReference [$item['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$item;

                // Remove items that were added to parents elsewhere:
                foreach($data as $key => &$item) {
                   if($item['parent_id'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']]))
                      unset($data[$key]);
                }
                $result = $data;
                break;

            case 'create_node':

                $node = isset($id) && $id !== '#' ? (int) $id : 0;

                $nodeText = isset($text) && $text !== '' ? $text : '';

                $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_node (id ,parent_id, name)
                VALUES (NULL,'".$parent."', '".$nodeText."')";

                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

                    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

                    $result = $last_id;
                }

                break;

            case 'rename_node':

                $node = isset($id) && $id !== '#' ? (int)$id : 0;

                $nodeText = isset($text) && $text !== '' ? $text : '';


                $sql_update_node_id = "UPDATE tb_node SET name = '".$nodeText."' WHERE id = $node";

                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_update_node_id)) {

                }


            break;
            case 'delete_node':

               $node = isset($id) && $id !== '#' ? (int)$id : 0;

                $sql = "DELETE FROM tb_node WHERE id=$node";

                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

                }

            break;

            default:

            throw new Exception('Unsupported operation: ' . $operation);

            break;
        }

    // Encode:
    echo json_encode($result);


}

$conn->close();
```

y la **base de datos** por si alguien desea usar y entender el código, o tambien puede acceder al sitio en donde esta la publicacion de este ejemplo de js con crud incluido. [jstreeCrud](https://monkeywebstudio.com/%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%99-jstree/)

```
    CREATE TABLE `tb_node` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

INSERT INTO `tb_node` (`id`, `parent_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, '0', '1'),
(2, '1', '2'),
(3, '1', '3'),
(4, '1', '4'),
(5, '1', '5'),
(6, '2', 'Hardware'),
(7, '2', 'Software'),
(8, '3', 'Java'),
(9, '3', 'PHP'),
(10, '4', 'Network 1'),
(11, '4', 'Network 2'),
(12, '5', 'การบริหารโครงการ 1');

ALTER TABLE `tb_node`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tb_node`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;
```

espero que  alguen sepa la menera de realizar esto. de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

debes implementar el evento select_node del JSTree:

```
...on('select_node.jstree', function (event, data) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (data && data.selected && data.selected.length) {
            var nodo = data.instance.get_selected(true)[0];

          // realizar una petición ajax pasando nodo.id como parámetro
        }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Francisco lo he agregado pero sin resultados, quizás lo este implementando mal, lo he colocado despues de [on('delete_node.jstree', function(e, data)] pero no me da resultado pues le puse un input dentro del if para que se llene con el id del nodo seleccionado pero no paso nada. en el siguiente comentario dejare lo que hice

Comment: on('delete_node.jstree', function(e, data) {


    $.get('crud_response.php?operation=delete_node', {
        'id': data.node.id
      })

      .fail(function() {

        data.instance.refresh();
      });

  }).on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (data && data.selected && data.selected.length) {
        var nodos = data.instance.get_selected(true)[0];
document.getElementById('idpar').value = nodos;
      // realizar una petición ajax pasando nodo.id como parámetro
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado aplicando el siguiente código al final de el [script] nos mostrara por alerta el id de el nodo que demos clic. luego este se podría manipular de la manera que queramos como para cargarle algún archivo a ese nodo o mostrar los archivo pertenecientes a un nodo en particular:

```
$("#frmt").on("select_node.jstree",
     function(evt, data){
     console.log(data.node.id);
     }
);
```

muchas gracias a los que se dedicaron a responder y leer el mi problema